How to use disposable variables in JavaScript?
I want to set a variable based on the result of a function call.. I don't want to call the function two times, or add an unncessary "temporary" variable to the function scope. I know it's probably premature optimization but I like doing that.
I can use the temporary variable obj inside a block scope like this:
function foo(){
    let output;
    calculate_output: {
        const obj = get_object();
        if(obj.x > obj.y){
            output = "x is greater than y";
        }else if(obj.x < obj.y){
            output = "x is less than y";
        }else{
            output = "x is equal to y";
        }
    }
    console.log(output);
    // more code that uses [output] below, so I don't want an unnecessary [obj] cluttering the function scope here..
}

But in order to do that, I have to make output a let which is.. wrong. It won't change value, so I want it to be a const.
The only way I know how to achieve this involves calling the function multiple times, like this:
const output = get_object().x > get_object().y ? "x is greater than y" : get_object().x < get_object().y ? "etc";

So is there another way I can calculate the value of output with temporary variables? Something like this:
const output = (const obj = get_object(); obj.x > obj.y ? "x is greater than y" : obj.x < obj.y ? "etc");


Some basic JS things: if you need a variable to exist in some larger scope, declare it there and then don't shadow it in your function (so you don't need to call a function just to get your variable). Also, JS is not Python: following the JS naming conventions: variables and functions use lowerCamelCase, not lower_snake_case. Also, if you have a normal function, don't use calculate_output: {.... It won't error, but it's guaranteed not what you actually wanted to do.

There are options, but the practical and efficient answer is to use let, unless it makes sense to factor your block out into a function.

Your use of let is the clearest way to do it, IMHO. There's no way to declare a variable that can be assigned only once and must remain read-only after that.
If you really want to use const, you could do it with ternaries in the initialization expression.


function foo() {
  const obj = get_object();
  const output = obj.x > obj.y ?
    "x is greater than y" : (
      obj.x < obj.y ?
      "x is less than y" : "x is equal to y"
    );
  console.log(output);
}



If the initialization requires even more complex logic, you could use an IIFE.

IIFE sounds like the only option then :D Thanks!
